# Get artists top song from current year in MPMediaQuery

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an application to get the top artist that was added to your music library within the current year (this is defined as how many songs in your library are from that artist). I currently have it working to get the top artist through the following code. Each artist does not have a date as the dateAdded property is only associated with each song in MPMediaQuery.songs().items - Is there any way I could sort through each artist to only get the ones with songs from the current year?

**My current code works, but it searches artists in your entire library, not just 2020**

```
func getTopArtist(){

var topArtist = ("None", -1)

guard let artists = MPMediaQuery.artists().collections else {
            return
        }

        for artist in artists {
            if artist.count > topArtist.1 {

                guard let artistName = artist.items[0].artist else {
                    return
                }
                
                topArtist = (artistName, artist.count)
            }
        }
        
        print(topArtist)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the structure that I have in mind is correct:

```
Artist {
 songs: [Song]?
 otherFields: Any?
}
```

A dummy approach would be to make a filter on the artist songs:

```
topArtist.songs.filter { return $0.year == 2020 }
```